# Pass array as individual values to params

Tags: c#, .net

I am calling a function which takes the same form as `string.format` where the first parameter is a string and the remainder are the replacement values.  I have the string in a variable and the replacement values in an array, how can I call this function given any number of objects in the array?  Simply passing in the array as the last argument does not work.

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: Did you write the calling function? Is it taking N parameters or just one Array parameter?

Comment: Passing in the variables as an array should work. Could you add the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function I was calling had the signature

```
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values)
```

Thhe issue was that I was passing in an array of ints as the last parameter.  When I createed a new array of objects poplulated from that initial array and passed it in it worked. Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 11):

Use the `params` keyword:

```
public string MyMethod(string value, params object[] args)
{
     // as an example
     return string.Format(value, args);
}
```

Then you can call it either with individual values

```
MyMethod("Test", "value1", "value2");
```

Or with an array

```
MyMethod("Test", new [] { "value1", "value2" });
```

Comment: Now, suppose I already have an array and I want to pass that to "MyMethod" which is defined with params object[] args. How do I pass the existing array so it doesn't end up as args[0]?

Comment: If your params is an object[] then you should just be able to pass any other type of array to it and covariance will implicitly cast it to object[]. If, for some reason, that doesn't work then you'll need to create a new object array containing the same values as the array you want to pass: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7yl7th

Answer (score 3):

you need to use the [**params**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28vs.71%29.aspx) keyword