# How to pass multiple parameters as an array in a C# Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am porting one of our node.js Azure Functions to C#, so this is C# running in a .csx container.  I'm running in the local Windows Function emulator and have also tried this in the Functions runtime in Azure, both show the same compiler errors.

I have seen [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350/how-to-pass-a-single-object-to-a-params-object) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032252/pass-array-as-individual-values-to-params) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21704990/passing-an-array-as-params-argument) asking something similar, but there seems to be something different about running in a .csx file or the functions runtime as none of the answers work.

This is the method signature that I'm calling :

```
DocumentClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<TValue> Method (Uri, Object[])
```

This is the working code from run.csx:

```
string param1 = "param1";
string param2 = "param2";

// object[] params = {"param1", "param2"};

var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<object>(
  sprocUri,
  param1,
  param2
);
```

When I try to add the two params into an array and uncomment the line `object[] params = {"param1", "param2"};` then I get this error from the compiler:

```
run.csx(72,14): error CS1001: Identifier expected
run.csx(72,14): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected
run.csx(72,21): error CS1002: ; expected
run.csx(72,21): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '='
run.csx(72,23): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '{'
run.csx(72,23): error CS1002: ; expected
run.csx(72,32): error CS1002: ; expected
run.csx(72,32): error CS1513: } expected
run.csx(72,42): error CS1002: ; expected
Compilation failed.
```

(Line 72 corresponds to the array assignment statement)

I have tried all of these different ways to define the array, but I get similar errors for each:

```
Object[] params = {"param1", "param2"};
object[] params = new[] {"param1", "param2"};
object[] params = new[] {param1, param2};
string[] params = {"param1", "param2"};
string[] params = new string[] {"param1", "param2"};
dynamic[] params = new[] {"param1", "param2"};
```

Is there something different about Azure Functions where it needs a different style of array definition?  There is nothing mentioned about arrays in the [C# Developer Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you named the variable `params` which is a reserved word in C# (see [params (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)). Try using a different name.

Should you be really set on using `params`, you could possibly use a `@` prefix which can be used in C# to create an identifier which would be a reserved word otherwise:

```
object[] @params = { param1, param2 };
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to args and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a secret to using an ArrayList instead of an object array in the method call?

Comment: @Graham no, it should be the same: `var args = new ArrayList { param1, param2 };` - as long as the method takes `ArrayList` as an argument, of course. Speaking of `ArrayList`, that is a class you mostly don't see past the first version of C# and/or legacy code. It might be more idiomatic to use `List<object>` to express "I really don't know the type" instead of "there is some type but I cannot express it" semantics of `ArrayList`. But that is only if you can change the method signature.